# How would one say "my computer died"?

Tags: word-requests

I know 关掉  to mean "turn off" but it doesn't seem to convey the sudden-ness or unwelcome connotation of "died". 突然关掉 is more precise but still seems to lack the negitivity. Also, as this is a common occurance, there must be a more colloquial way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If it hangs (not responding to any input), you could say

> 我的电脑**死机**了。

If the screen blacks out, you could say

> 我的电脑**黑屏**了。

If it doesn't turn on, you could say

> 我的电脑**不亮**了。

or

> 我的电脑**打不开**了。

If it is completely broken and needs major repair, you could say

> 我的电脑**坏了**。

or

> 我的电脑**完蛋**了。

Note: All above are used in Mainland China. I know they're expressed differently in other Chinese-speaking regions (e.g. Taiwan) but I don't know what they should become.

Comment: Nice answer. :)

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, usually we say:

**我的電腦當機了。**
(My computer crashed.)

or

**我的電腦壞掉了。**
(My computer is broken.)

or

**我的電腦不能用了。**
(My computer can't be used anymore.)

and I think people can understand when you just simply translate it

**我的電腦死了。**
(My computer died.)

From Taiwan, but only from my experiences...

Comment: I think the last three are common across all species of Mandarin, but the first is chiefly Taiwan. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3):

The expression is `死机` as in:

> 今天早晨我的计算机死机,所有的文件都丢失了.
>
> My computer crashed this morning and I lost all my documents.

Answer (score 1):

I would translate "my computer died” to 我的电脑死机了.

I'd like also to comment on the differences bwtween the following words, based on my understanding. I would use

- 死机 when computer is running well but suddenly halts and gives no response but seemingly still running and still power-on.
- 当机 when computer is running well but suddenly shuts itself down automatically and maybe power-off as well.
- 坏了(坏掉了) when computer hardware/software is damaged and can't be started up.
- 完蛋了 when computer is totoally ruined (like fall into water)
- 不能用了 to cover all the cases above as a summary conclusion.